# Android camera face detection does not work the second time

Tags: android, android-camera

I copied the code Google example in:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

For the first time I open the Camera, face detection works correctly and the callback is fired, I take the photo, close the camera, open the camera again but this time the face detection callback is not called.

If I'll restart my app, the same thing will happen - face detection will only work for the first time I'll use the camera.

here is my code:

```
private PictureTakenListener mPictureTakenListener;
AlertDialog mAlertDialog;
private Camera mCamera;
boolean mFaceDetectionAvailable;

private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        showText("took a photo with a size of " + data.length);
        releaseCamera();
        if  (mAlertDialog != null) mAlertDialog.dismiss();
        mPictureTakenListener.photoTaken(data);
    }
};


public class MyFaceDetectionListener implements Camera.FaceDetectionListener {

    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
        if (faces != null)
            if (faces.length > 0)
                if (faces[0].score >= 40)
                    if (!takingPhotoFlag.get()){
                        takingPhotoFlag.set(true);
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
    }
}

private void takePicture(PictureTakenListener listener){
    mPictureTakenListener = listener;
    if (this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        showText("this device has a camera");
        showText("device has " + String.valueOf(Camera.getNumberOfCameras()) + " cameras");
        int foundCamera = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++){
            Camera.CameraInfo info =  new Camera.CameraInfo(); ;
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                foundCamera = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundCamera  == -1){
            return;
        }
        mCamera = null;
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(foundCamera); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            showText("could not open the front camera. " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        showText("successfully opened the camera");
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
        params.setRotation(270);
        params.setPictureSize(640, 480);
        mFaceDetectionAvailable = params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0;
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        if (!mFaceDetectionAvailable) {
            frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            });
        }
          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        if (!mFaceDetectionAvailable)
            alert.setTitle("CLICK IMAGE TO CAPTURE");
        alert.setView(frameLayout).setCancelable(true).setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                releaseCamera();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //do UI stuff...
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mAlertDialog = alert.create();
        mAlertDialog.show();
        mAlertDialog.getCurrentFocus();
        mAlertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(960, 1280); //Controlling width and height.
        mAlertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        CameraPreview mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        frameLayout.addView(mPreview);
    } else {
        showText("no camera on this device");
    }
}

public interface PictureTakenListener{
    void photoTaken(byte[] image);
}




/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            if (mFaceDetectionAvailable) {
                mCamera.startFaceDetection();
                mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new MyFaceDetectionListener());
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(null);
        mCamera.stopFaceDetection();
        mCamera.setErrorCallback(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        showText("released camera");
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: same issue here, have you figured it out?

Comment: Nope. At this point I don't think it's possible

Comment: Can you confirm that mCamera.stopFaceDetection() is getting called? I had the same problem when I started face detection and then killed process from Android Studio. But it worked when I cleanly closed the app and restarted.

Comment: @ravindu1024 Sorry for the delay, I can confirm that is called.

Comment: @user3913439 I tried your code and I get the callback everytime i open it. Maybe its a device specific issue? (Also may I just say, for readability's sake, always use braces after an 'if' condition unless the conditional code is just one line)

Comment: I had same issue I feed jpg instead of camera.